# on Session "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to fill session if its null, getting error on null check

```
public static int ReportGroupId()
{
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportGroupId"] == null) <ERROR HERE>
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportGroupId"] = BL.Reporting.GET.ReportGroupId();

        return Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportGroupId"]);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are **recursively calling** your function `BL.Reporting.GET.ReportGroupId()` if the `Session` is `null`. That is why you are getting `Stackoverflow` exception. It is going into an infinite loop.

[Debug your code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)  and you will see that on first condition when session is null it is calling your method again.

I can only guess that you probably wanted to call some different function to get value of `GroupID` if it is not found in session.

Comment: yeah sometimes I am being blind. I need to call BL.Reporting.ADD.ReportGroup(); thanks for your time :)